# I want to create a reactive form with multiple components and would like to validate all mandatory fields when user clicks Submit button

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-material-8

I would like to create a angular reactive form with multiple sub components.

I would like to validate Parent and child form components in one go (When user clicks Submit button).

In my current scenario I was able to show the error message only in the parent form but not in the child components unless I touch those in the child components.

Here are the stackblitz Editor link --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kenydb

App link --> https://angular-kenydb.stackblitz.io

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use the same form group for children elements as well, no need to create a separate form group or child elements.

Comment: Thanks @Poojan, I gave a try but it doesnt working. Is it possible for you edit the stackblitz?

Comment: @GopikrishnaMandapati Caught up in some work but you can refer to this blog its self explanatory [link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-nested-reactive-forms-using-cvas-b394ba2e5d0d)

Answer (score 0):

You can use form group and add all the elements inside on form group.

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
  Name: <input formControlName="name"  placeholder="Enter Name">
  Age: <input formControlName="age"  placeholder="Enter Age">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: I want to include child components in the same form and I should also able to validate the elements (including child components).